# What's a good way to create a simple but good-looking web page that builds a report of an Excel file and shows Pandas dataframes and plots?

Tags: python, pandas, html, bokeh, dashboard

I want to create a simple web page that will *display a nice-looking dasboard-like report after I give it one or more .csv/.xlsx files*. The data processing I will do with Pandas and for plotting I plan to use either seaborn, bokeh or chartify, but what should I use for diplaying the tables and figures on a web page? I would prefer a quick and simple way to do this but in a stylish and customizable way.

I know only Python and some basic html. Should I use Flask or Dash? Or just save the images etc. and do everything with html or javascript? Or something else? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the PyViz tools, and specifically Panel, which makes it easy to build custom dashboards. See [pyviz.org](http://pyviz.org) and [panel.pyviz.org](http://panel.pyviz.org). You'll want to decide early whether you want a static HTML output or something with a live Python server, and set things up accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/) or [quart](https://github.com/pgjones/quart) as it is so simple to create web based applications like so:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)  
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

or quart:

```
from quart import Quart
app = Quart(__name__)
@app.route('/')
async def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```